# Is it possible to censor edit summaries in the revision history?

Tags: discussion, revision-history, edit-summary

Today I stumbled upon a question, which had been edited a few times. The reason for the first edit was set to:

> spelling gave me cancer

This message was copied and extended in an additional edit by another user.
I flagged this question for the following reason:

> Please check the edit history for this question. Some people included the reason "spelling gave me cancer", which I find somewhat offensive. A lot of people actually die of cancer and it's not something to make fun of/abuse like this. Could this please be revised? Thank you!

The flag got the response `useful`, but it came with a note:

> There's nothing a moderator can do about this.

So that makes me wonder, can the site admins maybe do something about this or is there anywhere else I can turn? It really bothers me to see cancer mentioned in such a way. There's no need to be throwing this awful disease around, let alone in an edit reason.

I'm pretty sure I'm not the only one that takes offense to this message, having lost several loved ones to this disease. So I really hope there's some way this message can be edited/removed.

Please note that I've deliberately not included the link to the question this is regarding, because I do not want to blame/slander the people that wrote it. I just sincerely wonder what I can do in cases when flagging does not achieve the desired goal, even though the flag has been marked as useful. I will be happy to send the link to someone that can take the appropriate action.

Comment: Spelling gave me gay cancer.  Also, mods can't change edit comments; they have to be removed by a dev/employee. Also also, whoever was "offended" by this comment is an idiot, and we should all point and laugh at his offense.

Comment: Some more clear cut examples: `lern to spell idiot!!`, `less moronic tags`, [`special edit dedicated to idiots`](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23058873/5) ([SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/388206) query with lots of false positives. Some people are really hard on themselves in their own edit comments.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree with you that the edit reason was insensitive and everybody would be better off if that person had written something else. Cancer is no joking matter, and I say this as somebody who has a professional hardening to it.

But you have to keep the purpose of the revisioning system in mind. It is there to ensure *transparency*. Its whole point is that history shouldn't be changed big brother style to hide things which disagree with our morals.

If such a message appears somewhere on the "face" of the site, in a question or answer, I'd be for editing it away. This is what our actual content is, what people see who come to use the site in the usual way. But a revision message is only seen by somebody who has come to take a look at the history of a message. Not only is such a person rare, their goal is likely to include some kind of inofficial auditing. And they have to rely on seeing the real history and not a changed one.

I know that this is not lived 100% that way. In rare cases, a revision can be removed from the history by a team member. This is only done for the purpose of protecting an innocent third party, e.g. if someone's personal information was published and out there for all bots to harvest.

But it is *not done to protect the sensibilities of an auditor*. Not only do I see the need for transparency as more important as the need for decorum in this case, I also think that an auditor should expect to find unsavory content every now and then. It's part of the job.

Comment: You are right, I suppose. A clean, uncensored version of the revision history does have a good purpose. I guess I'll just have to do another facepalm and realize once more how ignorant people can be with their remarks sometimes. Thanks for your response, this is a good point of view which I hadn't thought of yet.

Answer (score 6):

Moderators can't edit revision messages. As far as I know only an SE employee with developer access could change anything there, and even then I'm not sure how easy this is. I haven't heard anything about a revision message edit tool so far, the only tool I know about is for hard deletion of a revision. So this is probably an annoying and not side-effect free action.

I think simply commenting on the post and telling the user that there are better ways to express this is the most efficient way to deal with this. Revision messages have very low visibility, and involving a Community Manager with dev access is a pretty heavyweight action that I don't think is necessary here. Just let the message fade into obscurity, almost nobody will read the revisions of an old post.

Comment: I don't know if posting a comment will be a good idea. Yes, it will inform the editor that their behavior is found unacceptable by at least one person. But it will also probably create a Barbara Streisand effect with gawkers diving into the history of that question, and probably a heated comment discussion consisting of "I'm not offended, so if you are, you are a moron" vs "how can you say this, my aunt died of cancer".

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm not looking to start a flame war or to point fingers to the persons that typed this in their edit message, so I don't think a comment is the way to go here (not for me personally anyway). Additionally, when posting a comment about it, it will send out the message to more people that something "nasty" is going on in the revision history, which would probably offend more people (unnecessarily). It's probably just best to sigh another time about the ignorance of some people and ignore their message. But thanks for thinking along either way!

Comment: Moderators have been able to edit revision messages for quite some time now... (probably not when this was posted but don't think it was long after?)

Comment: Ahh - about two months after: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59597/allow-mods-to-edit-revision-comments/273359#273359